# Docx4j - Copy all the contents of a page into another document in place of a Place Holder

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

Is it possible to copy all the contents (elements) of a page into another document in place of a Place Holder.

I am using Text Place Holders in template, and i am able to add images, text, paragraphs, tables, on those place holders. I have a requirement, where i have to copy all the pages of a word document (different document) and paste those pages in place of a place holder in template.

I am using Docx4j for this..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement. I used the code in the blog post.

http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/html-altchunk-t933.html

hope this helps you.